# htaccess throwing 500 error

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^read(.+)?$ /read.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^chapter(.+)?$ /readchapter.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^list(.+)?$ /list.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Above is my htaccess file, I trying create a story reading website.

I trying to shorten example link of

```
http://read.mydomain.com/chapter/three_little_fox/
```

So when it query

```
/chapter/three_little_fox
```

It will actually load readchapter.php?id=three_little_fox

But when I try load the page

```
http://read.mydomain.com/chapter/three_little_fox/
```

It throws a Internal 500 error.

Thanks for helping

The current .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^chapter/([^/]*)$ readchapter.php?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But the 404 error exist, my folder is this way

```
.htaccess
readchapter.php
index.php
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^chapter **/** (.+) **/** ?$ /readchapter.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: @AmitThakur I used that recommendation still get 500 error.

Comment: 500 is a server error and not a PHP error; again, check your logs.

Comment: @Fred if I remove the htaccess, no more 500 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^chapter/(.*)/?$ /readchapter.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

RewriteCond (Rewrite Conditions) ensures that if the request is already for a file or directory, RewriteRule will be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^chapter/([^/]*)$ /readchapter.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: It give me 404 error now, but I got the file readchapter.php on the same folder.

Comment: I updated the code. Also, you are using a sub domain, so make sure the sub domain holds the .htaccess file and not the top level

Comment: It still give me 404 error, the code seems the same as just now

Comment: @Hydehanfu is there a rewriteBase in your .htaccess file?

Comment: @AmitThakur  no there is no rewrite base

Comment: @AmitThakur Sad to say, its still give a 404 error. added the updated htaccess on my question

Comment: @HydeHanFu is there a 'read' folder inside the public_html directory which is the folder that houses readcategory.php file? Or does the readcategory.php file live inside the public_html folder?